# how to close popup form automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a popup form in html based website ,in popup form there are three options,if I click on first option then it goes to that particular section,but popup form remains there.if I click on close then form will close.but I want automatically form close if I visit particular section.
below is my code.
[Picture of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEacK.jpg)

```html
<html>
<body>

        <!-- popup form start here -->
<div id="popScroll">
<div class="popScroll">
<div class="popup">
<div id="option">
<!-- <a href="index2.html" id="home" class="boxi">Home</a>  -->
 <!-- <a href="#" id="close" class="boxi closei">Close</a>  -->

<!-- <button class="btn" id ="close-btn"> Close </button>  -->
<div class="text">
<a href="#"><img src="demo.png" alt=""></a><br>
<a href="#">Chemical</a>
</div>
<div class="text">
<a href="#logistics" on><img src="demo.png" alt="logistics"></a><br>
<a href="#logistics">logistics</a>
</div>
<div class="text">
<a href="#polymer"><img src="demo.png" alt="polymer"></a><a href="#polymer">Polymer</a>
</div>
<!-- <span onclick="document.getElementById('popScroll').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright" class="boxi">Close</span> -->
</div><br><br>
<span onclick="document.getElementById('popScroll').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright" >Close</span>
</div>
</div>   
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: please post your code and not an image of your code

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but I assume you want to close a popup whenever you scroll down to a certain section within your site?

To achieve this, you could use the Intersection Observer.
More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add click functionality on options using click listener and close modal after a user clicks on options.

```
// NOTE: choose appropriate id according to your code

const popup = document.querySelector('#popup'); // id is popup id
const first = document.querySelector('#first'); // first is id of first option

first.addEventListener('click', function sectionClickListeners() {
  // Perform some tasks...
  popup.style.display = 'none';
})
```

This website gives a good understanding of using modals and gives different examples.
https://jquerymodal.com/